# Excel 2010 - Error: Cannot run the macro SelectCell using .onAction

Tags: vba, excel

I have been looking all over the internet for a solution to this problem but for some reason I can never find anything directly related to using .onAction with selecting a specific cell.

I am using an answer to another question as a reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18199035

In the section where it is looping through shapes, the script assigns an .onAction event to each shape. Whenever this is run in Excel 2010 I get the error:

```
Cannot run the macro "SelectCell "Sheet 1","$C$10"". 
The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

I am new to VBA scripting for excel so I have no idea if it is the formatting, but I know it is related to this line.

```
.OnAction = "'SelectCell """ & ws.Name & """,""" & cll.Address & """'"
```

I created a sub-procedure for SelectCell to display the values being sent as a debug. Same error.

I tried having excel allow all macros and disable all macros but it had no effect on the error.

If anyone has any idea of where I am going wrong or any resources I can use to further educate myself, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is SelectCell defined - in a regular module, or in a sheet module?  Does it run if you remove the parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This (both subs in a regular module) works for me.

```
Sub SelectCell(sht As String, rng As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Range(rng).Select
End Sub

Sub Assign()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).OnAction = "'SelectCell """ & _
            Selection.Parent.Name & """, """ & _
            Selection.Address() & """'"
End Sub
```

If `SelectCell` is in a sheet code module, then you need to include the sheet code name:

```
Sub Assign()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).OnAction = "'Sheet1.SelectCell """ & _
            Selection.Parent.Name & """, """ & _
            Selection.Address() & """'"
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

If I'm reading this right, "SelectCell" is a macro name, and you're passing in "Sheet 1","$C$10" as parameters (as strings).  Whenever you make a call on the right side of an assignment operator (equals sign) the parameters need to be passed in with parenthases.  for example,

```
.OnAction = "SelectCell "Sheet 1","$C$10""
```

is wrong, and

```
.OnAction = "SelectCell ("Sheet 1","$C$10")"
```

is right.

Try that, but there's not much I can go off without much code.  You could also try to use the fully qualified macro name, in case the Macro is in another module.

Comment: That does not work without the enclosing single-quotes, and it's not necessary to use parentheses when passing parameters to onAction.

Comment: try to use the fully qualified macro name, see if that works.  Ex- VBAproject.module1.selectCell