# How to call a macro from a button and pass arguments

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a button to my excel worksheet which should call a macro that can handle one agument (an integer value). Sadly when creating the button, I cannot link any macro that has arguments. Also just typing the macro and the argument does not work.

Is there any simple solution to pass an argument to a macro when a button is pressed?

Comment: You can actually type the macro name and argument enclosed in single quotes (eg `'macro 5'`) but don't use this method if your file is in .xlsb format.

Answer (score 46):

Yes, you can assign a macro to a button (or other excel controls/menu actions) and pass constant OR variable arguments to it.

In the 'Assign Macro' window (right-click on object and select 'Assign Macro'):

- Enclose the macro name in single quotes 
  e.g. to pass 2 constants: `'Button1_Click("A string!", 7)'`
- Select 'This Workbook' for the 'Macros in' field
- If you wish to pass a variable (like the value of a cell), enclose the parameter in Evaluate()

For example, to pass the value of `Sheet1!$A$1` to a button function, you would have the following text in the 'Macro name:' field:

```
Button1_Click(Evaluate("Sheet1!$A$1"))
```

If you don't enclose your variable argument with an 'Evaluate' function, excel returns the error 'Formula is too complex to be assigned to an object.'.

I would have included an image if this were allowed on my first post.

Comment: I have tried your approach, but I was not able to make it work. Seems that a function or macro is not allowed as an assigned macro if it receives arguments.

Comment: Enclosing the macro name is quotes worked for me: I set the macro name to `'Select 1,2'` for a button and it called my `Select` method correctly.

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked for passing a single argument - what if there are multiple arguments?

Comment: For multiple arguments, repeat the 'Evaluate(...)' component: 'Button1_Click(Evaluate("Sheet1!$A$1"), Evaluate("Sheet1!$A$1"), ...)'

Comment: The parentheses [must be removed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040102/11683). `'Button1_Click "A string!", 7'` works, `'Button1_Click("A string!", 7)'` does not.

Comment: Have you actually tried it in this exact context? Newer versions of office may have changed this and what you say makes sense in most VBA, but this case isn’t most VBA :) I think they may be using a different expression parser, because when I wrote this, they were absolutely required or it didn’t work.

Comment: How does this change for passing a range?

Comment: `Sheet1!$A$1` is a range.

Comment: Hum... `Evaluate` is a VBA function. You're executing a VBA function in the macro-assignment. Could *other* VBA functions be used there?

Comment: Wow, turns out you can use other VBA functions in the macro assignment. This works too: `'Button1_Click(Left("abc", 1))'`

Comment: Custom VBA functions work too, which could make this technique rather powerful.

Comment: You can also just pass the cell-address as text, and let VBA evaluate it. In that case, your VBA function should expect a String parameter.

Comment: This method no longer works for Microsoft 365 (Build 16.0.16130.20806) 64bit): `Cannot run the macro 'xyz'/ The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros maybe disabled`

Comment: Doesn't work with current version of Excel :( If I only have a single argument it's fine. But for 2 arguments I tried all the tricks above and nothing helps.

Answer (score 16):

Suppose you have a public sub take 1 argument like below (just for explanation purposes.)

[image: Macro]

And you insert a button on Worksheet like below, and you can not find the macro name when you want to assign your sub to this button.

[image: Button]

Now, you can type in your sub name + space + argument manually in single quotes, like below, click ok.

[image: Type macro name]

Then you see, problem solved.

[image: Result]

Comment: This absolutely should be the answer.  The OP was looking for how to do it via the assign macro screen, not via code.

Comment: Also would like to point out if your arrow keys do not work to add the quotes, you can still use the mouse to move the cursor to the right location.

Answer (score 6):

Use an activeX control command button and in the button click method, call the sub and pass the argument:

```
Private Sub CommandButton_Click()

  Dim x as Integer
  x = 1
  Call SomeSub(x)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Sub ert()
Call ert2(Cells(1,1).Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are the arguments OP asked for?

Answer (score 4):

To call this Sub from a button :

```
Public Sub TestButton(strMessage As String)
    MsgBox strMessage
End Sub
```

... be aware that the Sub won't be listed in the available macros, because it has a parameter. Just type in the call in single quotes : `'TestButton "Hello"'`

Answer (score 3):

Called from a regular "forms" button on a worksheet you can do something like this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim c, arr
    c = Application.Caller
    arr = Split(c, "_")
    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then MsgBox "Got " & arr(1)
End Sub
```

Where the calling button is named (eg) "Button_3"

Or (simpler) right-click the button and enter `'TestMe2 5'` (Including the single-quotes)

```
Sub TestMe2(i)
    MsgBox "Got " & i
End Sub
```

See also: [Excel 2010 - Error: Cannot run the macro SelectCell using .onAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305495/excel-2010-error-cannot-run-the-macro-selectcell-using-onaction/26307126#26307126)

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with my version of Personal.xlsb!'testForXXXX("Test Test")'. I got an error when clicking the button containing the Macro.

However, I was able to fix it by removing the "(" and ")". So, Personal.xlsb!'testForXXXX "Test Test"' worked (notice the space between testForXXXX and "Test...").

In fact, I didn't need Personal.xlsb! and was just able to use 'testForXXXX "Test Test"'.

Answer (score 1):

I would have liked to comment the answer by QA Collective but I do not have enough reputation point yet. Previous solutions did not work for me, as my macros are in named modules in my VBA project.

With Excel 2013, the way to pass a parameter to a macro using a button that worked in my context is :

```vb
'<module name>.<macro name> <parameter>'
```

e.g

```vb
'DataProcessor.disle "myText"'
```

or

```
'DataProcessor.editWSProcess True'
```

(boolean do not need double quotes when passed as parameters)
Please note that single quotes are around the whole expression.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue with the `assign button` not being very useful until I realised that all the potential `macros` displayed were only the ones in my **`Personal.xlsb` file that took no arguments**. Then I typed `Personal.xlsb!'macroNameWhichTakesArguments("arg1", ...)'` and the sheet picked it up.

I.E. `Personal.xlsb!'testForXXXX("Test Test")'`

Where the `macro testForXXXX` take a string as input, then the sheet worked ok.

When you use the assign macro route for a `button in excel 2007` at least `testForXXXX` will not show up in the list of potential macros if it takes args.

I suspect Aaron C got tripped up by this too. Maybe its best not to use a `Personal.xlsb` file?

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 16 (2024) I had to use the following pattern to make it work:

```
'<WorkbookName>.xlsm'!'MyFunction 1, "foo"'
```

where the macro was:

```vb
Sub MyFunction(ByVal Index as Integer, ByVal Name as String)
    ' ...
End Sub
```