# How can assign macro that is in WorkSheet module and has several arguments to a command button for Insert new TableRow in protected Sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Command button in my Worksheet `("Sheet1")`, under a Table.

My sheet is protected and I need let user add new rows.

Bellow macro was wrote for do that: (This is in a WorkSheet module)

```
Sub TblNewLine(Sht As String, Tbl As String, Pass as String, Filtering As Boolean, Pivot As Boolean)
if Nor Pass = vbNullString then
    Dim strP as String
    strP = InputBox ("Please input Password","Password")
    if Not strP = Pass Then
        if not strP = vbNullString Then MsgBox "Wrong Password!", vbCritical, "Error!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
    Sheets(Sht).Unprotect
    Sheets(Sht).ListObjects(Tbl).ListRows.Add
    Sheets(Sht).Protect AllowFiltering:=Filtering, AllowUsingPivotTables:=Pivot
End Sub 'TblNewLine
```

for example: arguments are:

`sht:= "sheet1", Tbl:="PvtReport", Pass:="", Filtering:=True, Pivot:= True`

Thus I need assign this macro to prepared command button that is under Table.

And passing arguments with pressing button.

In assign macro form, I cant find above macro in Macro names combo box.

How can I assign above macro and its related arguments to a command button?

Or is there any better solution for Insert new row to protected sheet Table?

Comment: Remove the `Private` keyword before `Sub`. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/309524/how-do-i-use-a-private-sub-in-excel) for details.

Comment: Removed, but not shown in assign macro, yet. when I write my subroutine name in Macro name field in Assign macro, its called. but there were problem of passing arguments to my subroutine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Call TblNewLine("Sheet1", "PvtReport", True, True)
End Sub

Sub TblNewLine(Sht As String, Tbl As String, Filtering As Boolean, Pivot As Boolean)
    Sheets(Sht).Unprotect
    Sheets(Sht).ListObjects(Tbl).ListRows.Add
    Sheets(Sht).Protect AllowFiltering:=Filtering, AllowUsingPivotTables:=Pivot
End Sub
```

**EDIT :**

---

See image for reference

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Seems there is no way to Pass arguments directly with a button.

Comment: How can I call `Buton1_Click` macro is there in `Sheet1` module by command button. Because `Button1_Click()` not found in Assign macro combo box.

Comment: You can simply write `Call Buton1_Click` but you should be able to see all sub names in `assign macro` list. Is it possible for you to share your workbook with dummy data so that I can have a look.

Comment: Of course. My Workbook has many Persian characters. When I write arguments in `()` for subroutine, the sub name been hide from `assign macro` list. And subroutines are in `Worksheets` module not shown in `assign macro` list.

Comment: @MGae2M - Try in VBA editor choose `tools>options>editor format> font which support your language`. Though I am not sure if this will solve your problem.

Comment: I'm ready to share my Workbook. Would you please invite me to a chat?

Comment: @MGae2M - You'll have to upload workbook online and share the link here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149314/discussion-between-mrig-and-mgae2m).

Answer (score 0):

With great thanks from [Mrig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6075259/mrig)'s guidance; For more explanation I Present whats i reached, as an answer:

there is a way for passing arguments with Command button, that I read in [QA Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858176/how-to-call-a-macro-from-a-button-and-pass-arguments)'s Answer for a related question.

At first i encountered 'cannot run Macro' error from Microsoft Excel, but when I closed and open workbooks document, looked Macro name field in Assign Macro was changed as bellow and my subroutine called truly by passing constants with click on button.

```
'FileName.xlsm'!'TblNewLine "SheetName", "tblReminder","",True,False'
```

Please not that ' character for enclose subroutine name and arguments list string, both in twisted '.

in above example, my sub needs 5 arguments so they pass with each command button that want calling this sub.

The point about assign macro that has no arguments, and there is in `Worksheet` module is there are listed below of `Asign Macro` combo list and not in order of subroutines are in other modules.

if subroutine macros has argument, there not listed in `Asign Macro` and should input them in related field as above example i explained.