# VBA sub with inputs

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How do I feed parameters into a sub? When I run a Macro, the sub just runs without asking for any input.

```
Sub do_something(input as integer)
    xxxxxx
end sub
```

I know I can use the sub in another sub/function where I can give it a input. Like the following,

```
sub caller_function()
    call do_something(1)
end sub
```

Is there another way to use do_something?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by *another way*?

Comment: According to how and where from you are calling the macro, there is different possibilities. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858176/how-to-call-a-macro-from-a-button-and-pass-arguments and https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/153307/how-to-call-microsoft-excel-macros-that-take-parameters for example

Answer (score 3):

Set up your sub something like this:

```
Sub do_something(param As Integer)
    MsgBox "The parameter passed to this Sub is " & param
End Sub
```

To call it:

```
do_something 1
```

---

If you want more than one parameter..

```
Sub do_something(param1 As Integer, param2 As String)
    MsgBox "The parameters passed to this Sub is " & param1 & " and " & param2
End Sub
```

To call it:

```
do_something 4,"Hello"
```

Or for a bit or reading chaos:

```
do_something param2:="Hello", param1:=4
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that you provided does not compile. Maybe you were trying to provide a simple example...?

It does not compile because `Input` is a reserved word, used to read data from a file object. You cannot use it as a variable name. (I have assumed that "xxxxx" is indicating where code should go, i.e. `'Do something here`.)

The following code works, but you cannot run it without passing a value:

```
Sub do_something(i As Integer)
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

If you want to make the variable optional, you can add the `Optional` keyword. Then it will run even if a value is not passed:

```
Sub do_something(Optional i As Integer)
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

You could also use a globally scoped variable, which would allow the sub to run without directly supplying a value:

```
Option Explicit

Public i As Integer

Sub do_something()
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

Regarding `Input`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/inputstatement

Answer (score -1):

With a single argument, you don't use parenthesis

```
do_something 1
```