# Passing two string arguments to Excel macro from button

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro that originally had 0 arguments, and called the macro from a button on my Excel sheet. The design changed, and now I added two optional arguments to the macro, like this:

```
Function ButtonClick(Optional prop1 As String, Optional prop2 As String)
    `Do stuff here
End Function
```

I am now trying to pass both arguments to the macro from the button, but get an error each time.

First I tried:

```
Sheet1.xlsm!ButtonClick(EVALUATE("A3"), EVALUATE("A4"))
```

as was suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858176/how-to-call-a-macro-from-a-button-and-pass-arguments), but got an error for `That function isn't valid`.

I noticed that in the question, the top answer also called for surrounding the entire macro name in single quotes, so I did so:

```
'Sheet1.xlsm!ButtonClick(EVALUATE("A3"), EVALUATE("A4"))'
```

And this time got there error `Formula is too complex to be assigned to an object`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why have `ButtonClick` be a *function* rather than a *sub*? You are calling it as a sub (so using the outer parentheses in `Sheet1.xlsm!ButtonClick(EVALUATE("A3"), EVALUATE("A4"))` is a syntax error, it should be `Sheet1.xlsm!ButtonClick EVALUATE("A3"), EVALUATE("A4")`. In general, it seems that you might benefit from researching the difference between functions, subs, and how they are called.

Comment: Dont make it a function, make it a subscript, make the optional a range, and only 1 not two. All you have to do is, select the two cells and open the macro menu and click run. thats one way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
'Sheet1.ButtonClick Evaluate("A3"), Evaluate("A4")'
```

With `ButtonClick` as a Sub. The single quotes are required.

Note this also works:

```
'Sheet1.ButtonClick [A3], [A4]'
```

since `[]` is a shortcut for VBA's `Evaluate()`

Comment: I tried this: `'Sheet1.xlsm!ButtonClick EVALUATE("A3"), EVALUATE("A4")'` with the same `Formula is too complex to be assigned to an object` error. When I tried `'Sheet1.ButtonClick EVALUATE("A3"), EVALUATE("A4")'` there was no error message, but the macro was never called

Comment: I got it to work by using just `'ButtonClick EVALUATE("A3"), EVALUATE("A4")'`. For some reason it didn't like the prefix of the sheet

Comment: Needs a period not `!`