# Excel Macro button not show macro with parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel macro, I try to write a testing macro named Test without parameter, and then in Excel workbook, press the macro button, the testing macro is shown as follow:

[image]

[image]

but if I add a parameter to the macro Test as

```
Public Sub Test(var1 As String)
```

then when I return to the workbook, press the macro button, the Test macro is not shown, why? Is macro cannot with parameter?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/31845993/5040941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro is not shown because you have forced a parameter to be passed as part of the procedure, thus rendering the procedure unavailable to be run on a stand-alone basis.

Comment: In fact I think it should still be shown, just when user press run button, force user to assign input parameter value

Comment: @user1169587 then remove the parameter from the procedure (so it is shown), and make the procedure ask the user for input unsing the [Application.InputBox method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox).