# Add a button and assign a function on press

Tags: excel, vba, button

On vba, I'd like to add a button and assign to it a function with a parameter.

That's code to the create the button (in module1):

```
Set testBtn = Worksheets("HOME").Buttons.Add(Position.Left, Position.Top, Position.Width * 2, Position.Height * 2)
With testBtn
           .OnAction = Send_click(ActiveSheet.Name)
           .Caption = "LOAD " & ActiveSheet.Name
           .Name = "LOAD " & ActiveSheet.Name
           .Font.Bold = True
 End With
```

while the function to call is defined in another module as:

```
Function Send_click(sheetName As String)
```

However, the button appears as not clickable and a macro LOADxxx_click appears as assigned (where xxx is the name of the ActiveSheet.name) but it clearly doesn't exist.

I have also tried suggestions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858176/how-to-call-a-macro-from-a-button-and-pass-arguments/31845993) and also to specify the module:

```
.OnAction = Module4.Send_click(ActiveSheet.Name)
```

with no different results.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd write another macro:

```
Sub ExecuteSendClick()

    Send_Click ActiveSheet.Name

End Sub
```

And assign that macro to the button.

Comment: Well, it is not exactly clean. But as a workaround does its job.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should assign a string value to the `.OnAction` property of a button object.

If the function (`Send_click` in this case) to be called is set to be public, then you just need to construct an `OnAction` string like this:

```
With testBtn
  .OnAction = "'" & "Send_click" & " " & """" & ActiveSheet.Name & """" & "'"
End With
```

The string concatenation part should return something like:

```
'Send_click "whatever_the_sheet_name"'
```